# Dynamically generate and populate Powerpoint from database values

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Here in a product manager capacity.

Our goal is to generate a powerpoint presentation that populates a pre-defined template using specific values in our database (Amazon RDS)

The values will be photos and text data.

Ideal flow would be:

> End user generates some data/photo output from other flows in our web application. All data will be in our database.
>
> The user clicks 'Generate Powerpoint'
>
> The application dynamically generates and populates the Powerpoint template with these values.
>
> The end user will be sales people, and with the greatest of respect, not super technical or willing to mess around with configuring.

We have been investigating some node.js solutions to generate PDF of the above, early prototypes are fine....but the beauty of PowerPoint is the sales people will then be able to make any minor edits one the document is generated.

What would be great to confirm with this community:

1) Is the above broadly possible?

2) Any existing components we could buy/license to speed up development?

3) Any technical/non-technical suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is almost certainly possible unless there are limits imposed by the database (I'm not familiar with it).  I have a commercial add-in that does something very similar, populates slides with text and images from Excel.

Comment: If you set up an ODBC connection in Excel (very easy, your IT people should be able to do this remotely) then run a predefined query to generate the data in excel, then Steve's addin would be able to update the PPT template for you.